# How can I solve this recursion question, I am really stuck.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recursion

I am doing a couple of exercise questions, How do I show that if we let  $n \geq 1$ be an integer, and if we consider $n$ people $P_1$,$P_2$,...,$P_n$. If we let $A_n$ be the number of ways these $n$ people can be divided into groups, such that each group consist of either one or two people.

How do we determine $A_{1}$, $A_{2}$, and , $A_{3}$
and how do we prove that for each integer $n\geq 3$,

$A_{n}$ = $A_{n-1}$ + $({n-1})$ $\cdot$ $A_{n-2}$

Comment: This is thinking off of the top of my head, but since you have the solution, it's easier to come up with an explanation.  Clearly you need $A_1 = 1$ and $A_2 = 2$ (where $A_2$ represents either 1 group of 2 or 2 groups of 1).  From those assumptions, can you figure out how to compute $A_3$?

Comment: In fact, this question and minor variations of it have been asked several times in the last week...

Comment: It wasn't solved, I don't really get the question and how to go about solving it.

Comment: You got stuck at the first step, finding the value of $A_1$? You have one person, call him Tom. How many ways can you divide him into groups of one or two? I can think of one way to do that: there is just one group, and that group is just Tom. Can you think of any other way to do it? If that's the only way, then $A_1=1$, right?

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1$, there is only one grouping : ${P_1}$.  That is, $A_1=1$. For $n=2$, there are two groupings: $\brace{\brace P_1, P_2}$ and $\brace {{\brace{P_1}}, {\brace {P_2}}}$. That is, $A_2 = 2$. Now let $n \geq 3$.
Consider any grouping of $n$ persons such that each group contains either $1$ or $2$ persons. Take the group containing the last person, $P_n$. Either that group contains only $P_n$ or it contains one more person. In the first case, the remaining $n-1$ persons can be grouped in $A_{n-1}$ ways and in the second case, $P_n$'s group-mate could be any one of the remaining $n-1$; those two form a group and the remaining $n-2$ can be grouped in $A_{n-2}$ ways. That is, number of groupings in the second case $= (n-1) A_{n-2}$.
Total number of groupings for $n$ persons, $$A_n=A_{n-1} + (n-1)A_{n-2}$$.